# php regular expression for start with number or alphabet mid contain <a href="

Tags: php, regex

I try myself to extract this type of links using explode but it not work maybe regular expression will helpful

links are :

```
01 &#8211; Root Books <a href="http://mylinkforgoogle.com.pdf" 

shokly  <a href="http://mylinkforgoogle.com.pdf"
```

i have dozen links in text file that i want extract i have no good knowldge but i want to try

```
php regular expression for start with number or alphabet mid contain <a href=" at end with .pdf
```

Comment: "maybe regular expression will helpful" If you have a problem and decide to solve it with a regular expression, you now have two problems

Comment: @MLeFevre you would have two problems if you don't know regex :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php

    $text = 'shokly  <a href="http://mylinkforgoogle.com.pdf'; 
    $link = strstr($text, 'http://');
    echo$link;

    ?>
```

Output:

```
http://mylinkforgoogle.com.pdf
```

I think this will be enough but if you are looking for pattern; it must be like this:

```
   <?php

$text = 'shokly  <a href="http://mylinkforgoogle.com.pdf"'; 
$pattern="/http:\/\/.[^w]*?\.pdf/i";
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => http://mylinkforgoogle.com.pdf )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
href="(.*?)"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jH5mH7/1)**

Code

```
$re = "/href=\"(.*?)\"/"; 
$str = "01 &#8211; Root Books <a href=\"http://mylinkforgoogle.com.pdf\" \n\nshokly  <a href=\"http://mylinkforgoogle.com.pdf\"\n"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you're not [parsing html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1504372)?

Here's a couple regexes that will do the job:

```
// @todo: This should be possible in 1 line
preg_match('/(?<=href=").*?(?=")/', $input_line, $output_array);
preg_match("/(?<=href=').*?(?=')/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

You can test them out [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/).